# Scrape dynamic websites using dart in flutter app

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, flutter, dart

I have a website that generates a list of items using some javascript and I am trying to scrape it inside my flutter app using beautiful soap package for dart. The thing is that I am unable to scrape the dynamic data generated by the java script. I want to implement a solution that allows me to grab the source code of the website after it fully loads inside the app. A hidden webview inside the app would be perfect but what is blocking me is that how to get the data after the webview loads. This is my main concern. Code examples would be appreciated. Also better practices are welcomed.

Comment: did you find a method?

Comment: no there is no progress.

Comment: I need this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have came to realize is that scraping dynamic websites that contain some javascript or a website that you want to click in it using a certain script to scrape it properly is not possible over flutter mobile. What you should do is to move the scraping to the cloud by creating your own api then using this api to return the response to your app. This will make scraping easier since you will not have to update your app for every error you find in your scripts. Also imagine that the website that you target updates itself every week, then you will have to update your app every week and wait for approval from all the stores you are  subscribed to. A simple example would be using **cloud functions** from firebase in combination with **javascript**  by utilizing the **puppeteer** package. A simple video tutorial is here: [Tutorial over youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMFS9fWiv98)

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research **I did indeed find a way**.

Basically loading a hidden webview and scraping the data off of it, then showing it on screen. Here's how..

**Spinning a webview in the UI**

The Visibility widget and width/height properties will make sure the webview is impossible to be seen by the user. I suggest showing a loading screen until the data is scraped.

```
             Visibility(
                visible: false,
                maintainState: true,
                child: Container(
                  height: 1,
                  width: 1,
                  child: WebViewPlus(
                    onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                      log.e("onWebViewCreated");
                      await model.onWebViewCreated(controller);
                    },
                    onPageFinished: (url) async {
                      log.e("onPageFinished");
                      await model.onPageFinished(url);
                    },
                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

**The actual scraping**

```
onWebViewCreated(controller) async {
      this.webViewController = controller;

      // Load the URL
      await controller.loadUrl("<Your Website URL Here>",headers:_apiService.getAuthHeader());

      // Get the HTML of the webpage as a JSON object
      String docu = await webViewController?.webViewController.evaluateJavascript('document.documentElement.innerHTML') as String;

      // Convert from JSON to String
      var jsonString = json.decode(docu);

      // Parse the String to a HTML DOM to actually access the elements
      var dom = parse(jsonString);

      // Some logic I needed in my application by scraping
      for (var child in dom.getElementById("autodl-log-tbody")!.children) {
        feed.add(child.text);
      }
  }
```

**Pro Tip** : If you think the webpage might need a bit more time to load, you can stall the execution of the function by using `await Future.delayed(Duration(Seconds:5));` before the line of code where you load the URL in the `onWebViewCreated()` function.